# Serve index.html by default on node http-server

Tags: node.js

```
http-server dist
```

works great for me on '/' but when using '/foo' it returns a 404. Is there an option for this module to serve 'index.html' by default for all routes?

Or does anyone know of a similar module with this functionality? I'm looking for a server that achieve this without any code (i.e capable from the CLI entirely)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try https://github.com/scottcorgan/pushstate-server

It works from CLI and it will server index.html for every route except your static assets

There is also a fork of http-server with implemented fallback

```
npm install skleeschulte/http-server --save
```

And then use -f or --fallback parameter:

```
http-server ./root -f /index.html
```